# Online Snake v0.1 with Python-flask and socketio

Tags: python, snake-game, flask, socket.io, websocket

What I am essentially doing is writing a snake game that everybody could play on the internet, broadcast their game if they like and so on. Now it looks like this, just websocket-based snake, no user authentication or everything. Pure and simple as possible.

Well, does my code follows best practices of coding both on server and client side? I am not sure adding extra fields to the `app` object is a good idea.

```
# Server.py
import time
from collections import deque

from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room
from flask.ext.socketio import leave_room, close_room, rooms
from flask.ext.socketio import disconnect

async_mode = None

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret"
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)

thread = None

from snake import GSnake
from snake import DIRECTIONS
from point import GPoint

b = deque()
b.appendleft(GPoint(x=0, y=0))
b.appendleft(GPoint(y=1))
b.appendleft(GPoint(y=2))
snake = GSnake(bodey=b)
tick = 1
app.paused = False
app.game_over = False

def restart_game():
    b = deque()
    b.appendleft(GPoint(x=0, y=0))
    b.appendleft(GPoint(y=1))
    b.appendleft(GPoint(y=2))
    app.snake = GSnake(bodey=b)
    app.paused = False
    app.game_over = False


def background_thread():
    count = 0
    cols, rows = 8, 6
    x, y = 0,0
    restart_game()
    while True:
        socketio.sleep(tick)
        if not app.paused:
            # print("f")
            app.snake.MakeStep()
        response = {}
        response["snake"] = app.snake.GetAsDict()
        response["game_over"] = not app.snake.is_alive
        response["apple"] = {"x":app.snake.apple.x, "y":app.snake.apple.y}
        socketio.emit(
            "field_change",
            response,
            namespace="/test"
        )
        if not app.snake.is_alive:
            restart_game()
            socketio.sleep(2)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@socketio.on('my event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    session['receive_count'] = session.get('receive_count', 0) + 1
    emit('my response',
         {'data': message['data'], 'count': session['receive_count']})

@socketio.on("turn up", namespace="/test")
def turn_up(message):
    app.snake.ChangeDirection(DIRECTIONS.UP)

@socketio.on("turn right", namespace="/test")
def turn_right(message):
    app.snake.ChangeDirection(DIRECTIONS.RIGHT)

@socketio.on("turn left", namespace="/test")
def turn_left(message):
    app.snake.ChangeDirection(DIRECTIONS.LEFT)

@socketio.on("turn down", namespace="/test")
def turn_down(message):
    app.snake.ChangeDirection(DIRECTIONS.DOWN)

@socketio.on("toggle pause", namespace="/test")
def pause(message):
    print("poop")
    app.paused = not app.paused

@socketio.on("restart_game", namespace="/test")
def restart(message):
    restart_game()

@socketio.on('my ping', namespace='/test')
def ping_pong():
    emit('my pong')


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    global thread
    if thread is None:
        thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=background_thread)
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected', 'count': 0})


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected', request.sid)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Client-side script. HTML contains just canvas and divs to render ping.

```
    function DrawSnakeBody(canvas, aray) {
        for (var i = 0; i < aray.length; i++) { 
            DrawSquare(canvas, aray[i], "rgb(50, 200, 50)");
        }
    }

    function DrawSquare(canvas, point, colour) {
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.fillStyle = colour;
        context.fillRect(point.x * 50, point.y * 50, 50, 50);
    }

    function DrawApple(canvas, apple) {
        DrawSquare(canvas, apple, "rgb(50, 50, 200)")
    }

    function DrawGameOver(canvas) {
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.font = "20px Arial";
        context.fillText("Game Over", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    }

    function RenderEverything(snake, apple, game_over) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("snake_field");
        var ccontext = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ccontext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        DrawSnakeBody(canvas, snake);
        DrawApple(canvas, apple);
        if (game_over) {
            DrawGameOver(canvas);
        }
    }
    namespace = '/test';
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
        if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
            socket.emit("turn right", {key: event.key});
        }
        if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
            socket.emit("turn left", {key: event.key});
        }
        if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
            socket.emit("turn up", {key: event.key});
        }
        if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
            socket.emit("turn down", {key: event.key});
        }
        if (event.key === " ") {
            socket.emit("toggle pause", {key:event.key});
        }
        if (event.key === "R") {
            console.log("Rfff");
            socket.emit("restart_game", {key:event.key});
        }
    }, false);

    document.body.onload = Main;

    function Main() {
        socket.on("field_change", function(msg) {
            console.log(msg.game_over);
            RenderEverything(msg.snake.bodey, msg.apple, msg.game_over);
        });

        socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
        });
        socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
            $('#log').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('Received #' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data).html());
        });
        // Interval function that tests message latency by sending a "ping"
        // message. The server then responds with a "pong" message and the
        // round trip time is measured.
        var ping_pong_times = [];
        var start_time;
        window.setInterval(function() {
            start_time = (new Date).getTime();
            socket.emit('my ping');
        }, 1000);
        // Handler for the "pong" message. When the pong is received, the
        // time from the ping is stored, and the average of the last 30
        // samples is average and displayed.
        socket.on('my pong', function() {
            var latency = (new Date).getTime() - start_time;
            ping_pong_times.push(latency);
            ping_pong_times = ping_pong_times.slice(-30); // keep last 30 samples
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < ping_pong_times.length; i++)
                sum += ping_pong_times[i];
            $('#ping-pong').text(Math.round(10 * sum / ping_pong_times.length) / 10);
        });
    }
```

Though snake itself is simple and not essential, I prefer to put it here.

```
# snake.py

from collections import deque
from random import randint
from point import GPoint

class GStruct:
    pass

DIRECTIONS          = GStruct()
DIRECTIONS.DOWN     = GPoint(x=0, y=1)
DIRECTIONS.UP       = GPoint(x=0, y=-1)
DIRECTIONS.LEFT     = GPoint(x=-1, y=0)
DIRECTIONS.RIGHT    = GPoint(x=1, y=0)

class GSnake(object):
    """docstring for GSnake"""
    def __init__(self, bodey=deque(), max_x=8, max_y=6):
        super(GSnake, self).__init__()
        self._current_direction = DIRECTIONS.DOWN
        self._previous_direction = DIRECTIONS.DOWN
        self._bodey = bodey
        self._apple = GPoint(x=randint(0, max_x), y=randint(0, max_y))
        self._max_x = max_x
        self._max_y = max_y
        self._bite_self = False

        self._GenerateApple()


    @property
    def head(self):
        return self._bodey[0]

    @property
    def apple(self):
        return self._apple

    @property
    def is_alive(self):
        a = 0 <= self.head.x < self._max_x
        b = 0 <= self.head.y < self._max_y
        c = not self._bite_self
        print(a, b, c)
        return a and b and c    


    def MakeStep(self):
        head = self._bodey[0]
        new_head = head + self._current_direction
        if new_head in self._bodey:
            self._bite_self = True
        self._bodey.appendleft(new_head)
        if new_head == self.apple:
            self._GenerateApple()
        else:
            self._bodey.pop()
        self._previous_direction = self._current_direction


    def ChangeDirection(self, new_direction=DIRECTIONS.UP):
        dd = self._previous_direction + new_direction
        if dd.x == 0 and dd.y == 0:
            pass
        else:
            self._current_direction = new_direction


    def GetAsDict(self):
        res = {"bodey": []}
        for point in self._bodey:
            res["bodey"].append({"x": point.x, "y": point.y})
        return res


    def _GenerateApple(self):
        apple = GPoint(x=randint(0, self._max_x - 1), y=randint(0, self._max_y - 1))
        while apple in self._bodey:
            apple = GPoint(x=randint(0, self._max_x - 1), y=randint(0, self._max_y - 1))
        self._apple = apple
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you question is? Fixing the bug or improving your code?

Comment: @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo, why not both?

Comment: Code review is all about reviewing a workable code not bugs

Comment: @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo, is my point clearer now?